# How to easily convert an MKV video to an MP4

Tags: video, convert, mp4, mkv

I would like to easily be able to convert a MKV video to MP4 video in Ubuntu. Is there any way I can easily do this at all?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One easy way (requiring a terminal), is using FFMPEG.

First, open a terminal and install FFMPEG with this command:

```
sudo apt install ffmpeg
```

Now all you have to do to convert your video is this one single command:

```
ffmpeg -i <inputfile> <outputfile>
```

For example, in your case:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv output.mp4
```

FFMPEG will automatically detect/use the correct input and output formats.

Conversion may take a few minutes based on length and frame rate of video.

Answer (score 0):

As a GUI for `ffmpeg` there is this tool: [dmMediaConverter](https://sites.google.com/site/dmsimpleapps/dmMediaConverter?authuser=0).

Very easy to use, but with subtitles I had to edit the subtitle codec and change to `mov_text`.

[image]